# wget won't stop after the surrounding subshell is killed

Tags: shell, signals, sh, wget, kill

See:

```
(wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask && echo 'ok' || echo 'failed') & pid=$!
sleep 1      # this is curcial
kill $pid
```

If took out the second line, there would be no hanging wegt after the script finishes.
What I want to achieve is to kill the wget process(or the subshell as a whole) at some time and do more processing based on the exit code of wget.
Can you explain to me why does wget in above script doesn't get killed properly, and how to make it so ? Or is there any way that I can achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
$ foo=foo
$ export foo
$ (foo=bar; echo foo is $foo); echo foo is $foo
foo is bar
foo is foo
```

A processes doesn't change its parent's environment.  That goes for shell processes and subshells, too.

Braces alter logical priority without creating a subshell:

```
$ foo=foo
$ export foo
$ { foo=bar; echo foo is $foo); }; echo foo is $foo
foo is bar
foo is bar
```

So I think you want

```
{ wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask \
  && echo 'ok' || echo 'failed'; } & 
kill $!
```

> I want ... to kill the wget process (or the subshell) ... and do more processing based on the exit code of wget.

I assume this example is simplified, and what you really want to know is whether wget completed successfully or not, and if it was killed.  All that information will be in `$!`, except that `echo 'failed'` will return true.  If that's an issue, trap the status before echoing the message.

Comment: thank you, but it does not work if you put sleep 1 before kill $!, I don't want to kill wget immediately, but after doing some work. I think in this case, both braces and parentheses create subshells as they all run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing `kill $pid`, do the follows:

```
wpid=$(ps -o pid=,ppid=,cmd= \
        | awk '$2 == '$pid' && $3 == "wget" { print $1 }')
[ -n "$wpid" ] && kill $wpid
```